What is the name of this film about a boy and girl who meet in hospital and fall in love
I've been searching all over the web for this film about a boy and a girl :-  

Who are about 15-17 years old  
Who are both living in hospital due to certain illness's  
There is also a doctor who introduced the two by the end of the film they become a couple and over come there illness
It is a Korean or Japanese film   
I am pretty sure it is a anime/manga adaptation as I've seen a anime very similar to the film   
The genres of this film are romance and drama


Believe you are looking for Looking Up at the Half Moon (2010 - Japan)
The synopsis...

Two 17 year old teens are hospitalized for different reasons. Ezaki
  suffers from Hepatitis A, while Akiba is due to a weak heart. The
  relationship between these two hospital patients soon blossoms into
  romance.

And it is based on an anime...
Hanbun no Tsuki ga Noboru Sora

subtitled looking up at the half-moon and also known as Hantsuki, is a
  Japanese romance light novel series written by Tsumugu Hashimoto and
  illustrated by Keiji Yamamoto centering on two hospitalized seventeen
  year olds and the love they begin to share. The series was originally
  serialized in MediaWorks' now-defunct light novel magazine Dengeki hp
  and spanned eight volumes released between October 2003 and August
  2006.

